# WPF / XAML TaskbarItemInfo : how to remove blank area for ThumbButtons?

Tags: xml, wpf, taskbar

I am using [Window.TaskbarItemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to set Overlay icons and show Progress state. This works well, however, even though I have no ThumbButtons set there is still a blank area for those buttons shown below the Thumbnail.

I can easily add buttons but not collapse that area. I tried explicitly setting the ThumbButtonInfos property to null or an empty collection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with using the WPF provided `TaskbarItemInfo`.

I would look into the packages called WindowsAPICodePack created by Microsoft.

You have to install [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core/) and [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) for it.

After your window has loaded you can set the overlay icon and progress state through the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.TaskbarManager` class. Example:

```cs
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap("d:\\icon.png"); // or get it from resource
    var iconHandle = bitmap.GetHicon();
    var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle);

    TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(this, icon, "Accessibility Text");
    TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState.Indeterminate, this);
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

You can see that I have an overlay and a progress bar set, but I don't have the empty button panel below the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I thought I would need another approach to set overlay and progress state via the Win API.